# How to import from parent directory using importlib in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I have a directory like this:

```
Project Folder
├─main.py
├─Utils
│  └─util1.py
└─Plugins
   └─plugin1.py
```

How can I import util1.py directly from plugin1.py? I tried using `importlib.import_module('Utils.util1', '..')`, but that didn't work. `from ..Utils import util1` and `from .. import Utils.util1` also did not work (`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`)

Please note: its not utils and plugins in my directory, I just named them like that here for ease.

Comment: Is the top-level project folder in `sys.path`?

Comment: try `from ... import utils.util1`

Comment: @JohnGordon nope

Comment: @Goldwave didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you could do:
not tested

```
import os, sys
currentDir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('..') # .. to go back one dir | you can do "../aFolderYouWant"
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
import mymodule
os.chdir(currentDir) # to go back to your home directory
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# From http://stackoverflow.com/a/11158224

# Solution A - If the script importing the module is in a package
from .. import mymodule

# Solution B - If the script importing the module is not in a package
import os,sys,inspect
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir) 
import mymodule
```

Comment: How can I know whether or not it is in a package?

Comment: It's probably not. I'd try Solution B